# Iterate .net constructor agruments

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, constructor, .net-4.5

I am possibly asking the impossible but I shall ask anyway. From the following:

```
public SomeClassConstructor(SomeOtherClass someOtherClass, string someString){
   ...
}
```

Is it possible to access the arguments so that they can be iterated (for example some sort of reflection to access an `IEnumerable<object>` that contains the arguments)?

Note: The params[] collection is not an answer in this situation. Other restrictions are that this is to be used in a WinForms environment; .Net 4.5 is acceptable.

EDIT: In response to DavidG's comment I am after the objects themselves (aka values and names). The reason being that I have a requirement to log (serialized) the arguments when a form is opened (when a UAT flag is set in app.config!). Large objects have their serialization over ridden to return simple strings so as not to bloat in memory.).

Comment: You want the values or just the names of the parameters? And form where do you want to access this from?

Comment: access to the objects; so names and values.

Comment: It's not really making sense what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: DavidG - I have updated my question with a little more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't access parameter values via reflection. You can get the names, types, attributes etc - but not the values. That's true of methods, constructors, property setters, indexers etc.

You could potentially do it in a debugger API, but that's almost never the right approach.

For logging, you should *either* just do this manually:

```
Log("someOtherClass={0}, someString={1}", someOtherClass, someString);
```

or look into AOP to inject calls automatically - look at [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) for example.

Comment: Jon: Thanks for the rapid reply! Currently I am using a "Log" style approach; I was just looking to see if there was a way I could automate this rather than having to add each param in each ctor.

Comment: @jamesakadamingo: Not within normal C#, no. There are some approaches which could make the code nicer to read, but using dynamic typing - which would probably have too high a cost for something like logging.